# SharePoint 2010 - Using SOAP web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've added a reference to a SOAP service in my VS2010 project.  I have a form that registers users for a newsletter.  For me to get this form to work, I have to edit the SharePoint server's web.config and add in the SOAP bindings.  If I don't do that and add it into my project's app.config, the server gives an error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'contractAPI.Soap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.

How can I bypass the web.config and use the app.config to configure the SOAP service or set this up programmatically using C#?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the bindings in your code like this:

```
internal static WServiceSoapClient CreateWebServiceInstance()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    binding.AllowCookies = false;
    binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
    binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
    binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
    binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
    return new WServiceSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://yourservice.com/service.asmx"));
}
```

Comment: I've tried that solution previously but I still get the same error.  The WebPart still looks into the web.config even after manually defining those values.

Comment: In my code where I use the web service, I use: WServiceSoapClient client = WebServiceHelper.CreateWebServiceInstance() instead of new WServiceSoapClient() and the config file doesn't get hit at all as all of the info it needs has been supplied in the binding.  Could you post some of your code?

Comment: I added the working SOAP config values along with what you posted.
'binding.Name = "SoapBinding";
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 65536;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";'